# Pine script - Table size in pixels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have created a table in Trading View (Pine Script), but the table is resized based on the available space. The problem is that on the laptop screen, some information is hidden...

The table always resizes when I change the window size... I'm looking for a way to fix it in pixels.
Do you think it is possible?

I wish to have a fixed width/height for every table cell... I already use the width/height parameters but it does not help. The goal is to optimize the space, now, either it is too small or too big.

I join some pictures, the first is with a big screen, the table eats all the space. The last one is on a laptop (quite small).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyr8W.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00SU9.png)

Comment: in the images the cells appear to be the same width, but the height is adjusting automatically
It seems that height doesn't have a fixed parameter, but I'm just assuming

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.